# Batch account node restarted unexpectedly

Tags: azure-batch

I am using an Azure batch account to run sqlpackage.exe in order to move databases from a server to another. A task that has started 6 days ago has suddenly been restarted and started from the beginning after 4 days of running (extremely large databases). The task run uninterruptedly up until then and should have continued to run for about 1-2 days.
The PowerShell script that contains all the logic handles all the exceptions that could occur during the execution. Also, the retry count for the task was set to 0 in case it fails.
Unfortunately, I did not have diagnostics settings configured and I could only look at the metrics and there was a short period when there wasn't any node.

What can be the causes for this behavior? Restarting while the node is still running

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to give a definitive answer to this question. You will need to dig into the compute node (interactively log in) and check system logs to give you details on why the node restarted. There is no guarantee that a compute node will have 100% uptime as there may be hardware faults or other service interruptions.

In general, it's best practice to have long running tasks checkpoint progress combined with a retry policy. Programs that can reload state can pick up at the time of the checkpoint when the Batch service automatically reschedules the task execution. Please see the [Batch best practices guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/best-practices) for more information.

Comment: I tried to look at the system logs for this node and I can only see the ones after the node was restarted. There isn't anything from when the node was started, even though it looks like it's the same node (from Azure portal: 
Last boot time Saturday, May 22, 2021, 12:05:01
Node allocation time Tuesday, May 18, 2021, 19:18:32)

Comment: Node allocation time is from the perspective of the Batch service, not if the node itself was recovered by Batch or the underlying Azure compute layer. Do your system logs go back further than the boot time? If not, then the node may have failed and recovered.